# Best way to store matrix of unknown size in relational database?

Tags: sql, database-design

The database I'm designing needs to store matrices of arbitrary size where each column has a description attribute and many-to-one relation with a table representing quantity (length, area, speed etc).

Current design has a table "ValueMatrix" which has a one-to-many relationship with table "MatrixColumn" (allowing for arbitrary width of the matrix). "MatrixColumn" in turn has a one-to-many relation with "ColumnRow", representing an element in the matrix (allowing for arbitrary length for each column).

**Is this considered correct/good design for storing a matrix in a relational database?** I realize that this is kind of an open ended question, but any comment and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated

[image: Diagram of current design]

Comment: Storing the matrix is the easy bit - can you give us any ideas about how you will be querying the matrix? Would you want to do things like "find all matrices where (x, y) has value ? and (a, b) has value ?".

Comment: @NevilleKuyt As of now I would typically query the whole matrix in one go, but I dont want my design to limit any future queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't follow exactly what your table structure is.  I would define a matrix with two tables:

```
create table matrices (
    matrix_id int generated always as identity primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    num_rows int,
    num_cols int
);

create table matrix_elements (
    maxtrix_element_id int generated always as identity primary key,
    matrix_id int not null,
    row int not null,
    col int not null,
    value ?,  -- whatever type is appropriate
    unique (matrix_id, row, col),
    constraint fk_matrix_elements_matrices foreign key (matrix_id) references matrices(matrix_id)
);
```

I would throw in a constraint that the `row` and `col` values are correct for the matrix.  How those inter-table constraints are implemented depends on the database.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I see you literally wrote a book(!) on the subject of sql, so I'll assume your answer is the best approach. Perhaps I should mention that the matricies size typically will be in the order of (100-5000)x(5-20). Does this have any bearing on your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to comment on what would be a good design without a more detailed use-case but I think I would have a design with two tables:-

**Table one**
PK
MatrixName
All other matrix level data

**Table two**
FK
X-coord
Y-coord
Value

There's some basic questions to consider:-
-How do you ensure the matrix retains it's basic structure at all times with the values you'd expect to be populated (especially if others going to be able to edit the values or add elements)?
-How to create them efficiently in the first place - Cartesian joins can sometimes help

Because the matrices are arbitrary sizes, I think you're forced into this x/y design which loses the conventional tabular design RDMS' are so good at.

Other software (like R) have a whole different way of handling matrices - it's free and efficient and might be worth a look if you can consider other options.

Best of luck to you,

Phil

Comment: Thanks! Your answer seems to agree with Gordon Linoffs answer; I'll give this approach a try

Answer (score 0):

I *think* your problem domain can be described thus:

```
They system has many *matrices*
A matrix has 0 or more *cells*
A cell is identified within the matrix by *coordinates* (x, y)
A cell has exactly one *numerical value*
A cell has exactly one *description*
A description applies to 0 or more cells
```

If that's the case, I think your tables are:

```
Matrix
--------------------
MatrixID (pk)
....

Description
--------------------
DescriptionID (pk)
DescriptionText 

Cell
-------------------
MatrixID (pk)(fk)
X (pk)
Y (pk)
DescriptionID (fk)
CellValue
```

This would allow you to retrieve the entire matrix in a single query:

```
select
m.matrixID, 
c.X, 
c.Y, 
c.CellValue, 
d.DescriptionText
from matrix m
inner join Cell c on c.matrixId = m.matrixID
inner join Description d on c.descriptionID = d.DescriptionID
order by c.x, c.y
```